# Am I Misunderstanding Protractor and the ControlFlow?

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

At my job we have some tests that are failing on my coworkers local machine but not on mine or the agent we run our tests on and we can't figure out why. I was under the impression that when you use protractor, each it is queued in the control flow and executed in order. What we're seeing on my coworkers machine is that subsequent its are being executed even though a promise in a previous has not been resolved. I've stripped out the work related details and hopefully the code snippet below is enough to understand what's going on.

Is my understanding of protractor wrong or could there be a problem on my coworker's machine?

```
"use strict";

describe('Test Title', function() {
    let fetchedData,
    createdData;

beforeAll(()=> globalHelper.logIn());
afterAll(()=> globalHelper.logOut());

it("Precondition: set to clean state", function () {
    environmentHelper.cleanEnvironment();
});

it("Get data from server", function () {
    fetchDataFromServer()
    .then((result) => {
        fetchedData = result;

    });//we expect execution of the test to stop until this promise is resolved and an error is thrown or the code inside the then is executed
});

it("Next Step", function () {
    //do some things
});

it("Next step", function (){
    //do more things
});

it("Navigate to page", () => {
    //navigate to page
});

it("create some data", function () {
    //create some data
});

it("another step", function () {
    //do even more things
});

it("Clean up", function() {
    environmentHelper.removeCreatedData(createdData);
  });

});
```

Any help  would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: A test represented by `it(...)` is supposed to be independent from the other tests. In your example you are using them as steps, which is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would add extra logging on `fetchDataFromServer` and maybe have a catch statement,

```
   it("Get data from server", function () {
     fetchDataFromServer().then((result) => {
       console.log('data fetched from server complete');
       fetchedData = result;
     }).catch(err => {
       console.error('something bad happened here);
     });
     //we expect execution of the test to stop until this promise is resolved and an error is thrown or the code inside the then is executed
   });

   it("Next Step", function () {
     console.log("next step");
     //do some things
   });
```

Protractor should wait for promises to resolve within the it block based on [`angular/jasminewd`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd). For `controlFlow`, selenium-webdriver queues up promises and resolves them in order, so when you send `browser.get` or `element(by.css('')).click`, they happen in order.